# Cancel further operations on context cancellation

Tags: go

I have a func that receives context and does some cpubound operations like bellow.

```
func DoSomeOperation(ctx context.Context){
    CPUBoundWork1()
    CPUBoundWork2()
    CPUBoundWork3()
    CPUBoundWork4()
}
```

What I want to do is to check if `Context` has been cancelled or not before making each CPUBound `func` call. If cancelled I want to return immidiately without making next func `call`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is `ç.Context` `context.Context`? If so, then yes. If not, then what is it?

Comment: Ya it is context.Context. @icza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ctx.Err()](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context)

```
if ctx.Err() == context.Canceled {
    return
}
```

You also can use [select](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) statement with `slice` of `functions`.

For Example:

```
    ctx := ...
    executors := []func(){...}
Loop:
    for _,executor := range executors{
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            if ctx.Err() == context.Canceled {
                break Loop
            }
            if ctx.Err() == context.DeadlineExceeded {
                //do something else
            }
        default:
            executor()
        }
    }
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://play.golang.org/p/y5K2s4c0ylK)</kbd>